# Multivariable continuity $f(x,y) = \frac{2x^2y}{x^4 + y^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

How do you show that the following 
multivariable function is continuous?

> $f(x,y) = \frac{2x^2y}{x^4 + y^2}$

I think I want to show that for every point $(x_0,y_0)$:

$\forall \varepsilon >0, \  \exists\delta >0$ such that $||(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)|| < \delta \implies |f(x,y) - f(x_0,y_0)| < \varepsilon  $

But I don't really get how to apply this.

Comment: Have you seen similar examples of functions of two variables for which continuity is shown?

Comment: I've seen an example on $f(x,y) = \frac{2xy}{x^2 + y^2}$ but it's just explained with it being continuous at all points except (0, 0) because of it being a rational function of two continuous functions where the denominator is >0, which doesn't seem to be all that formal to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's indeed what you want to show but there is an easier way to prove continuity. What I would do is use the fact that composition, multiplications and additions of continuous functions are continuous. And since you know that $\frac{1}{x}, 2x^2 y$ and $x^4 + y^2$ all are continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0) \}$ that should be enough