# Multivariable continuity $f(x,y) = \frac{\sin x \ +\ \sin y}{x\ +\ y}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

How do you show that the following multivariable function is continuous?

> $f(x,y) = \frac{\sin x + \sin y}{x +y}$

I think I want to show that for every point $(x_0,y_0)$:

$\forall \varepsilon >0, \  \exists\delta >0$ such that $||(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)|| < \delta \implies |f(x,y) - f(x_0,y_0)| < \varepsilon  $

I know that the function is not continous at $x = - y$ as the denominator is undefined then.

$\sin x$ and  $\sin y$ are continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ as is $\frac{1}{x+y}$ (except for x = -y)

Comment: Are you going to ask all of your homework questions here?

Comment: The first one: that I asked here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3180886/multivariable-continuity-fx-y-frac2x2yx4-y2 didn't really help me with the general approach towards solving these types of problems, which is why I am asking and once again included the $\forall \varepsilon >0, \  \exists\delta >0$ such that $||(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)|| < \delta \implies |f(x,y) - f(x_0,y_0)| < \varepsilon  $ which is still the part that I don't quite get.

Comment: "I know that the function is not continous at =−." If $x= -y$ then the function is not defined. Continuity has no meaning at $x = -y$.

Comment: You rarely use the definition of continuity to prove it, you use that composition of continuous functions is continuous. Unless you are explicitly told to find it using the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is continuous on $\mathbb{R}-D$, where $D$ is the diagonal $ \left\lbrace (x,-x), x \in \mathbb R\right\rbrace$, since the numerator and the denominator are continuous, and the denominator is not zero.

Let $a=(x,-x)$ and $a_n$ a sequence of $\mathbb{R}^2$ going to $a$. Let $a_n=(x_n,y_n)$.

$$
\sin(x_n)+\sin(y_n)=2\sin((x_n+y_n)/2)\cos((x_n-y_n)/2) \sim 2 \dfrac{x_n+y_n}{2}\cos((x_n-y_n)/2)
$$

since $x_n+y_n \to 0$

Consequently $f(x_n,y_n) \sim\cos((x_n-y_n)/2) \to_{n\to\infty} \cos(x)$.

If you define $f(x,-x)=\cos(x)$ then your function is continuous at $a$.

And finally $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "define $f(x,-x) = \cos x$" ?

Comment: Right @Digitalis, fixed

Answer (score 0):

Change the coordinates to $u=(x+y)/2$ and $v=(x-y)/2$, so that $x=u+v$ and $y=u-v$. Then we have

$$f(x,y)={\sin(u+v)+\sin(u-v)\over2u}={(\sin u\cos v+\cos u\sin v)+(\sin u\cos v-\cos u\sin v)\over2u}={\sin u\over u}\cos v\to1\cdot1=1$$

as $(u,v)\to(0,0)$ (along any path with $u\not=0$).